# amd radeon Graphic device driver error on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, graphics, 16.04

Why is there no support for AMD radeon graphics devices on 16.04? And why usb fdd is undetectable on 16.04?

Comment: You (we) should wait till 16.04.1

Answer (score 0):

Starting 16.04, there will not be any closed source drivers for ATI graphics card i.e. no fglrx drivers. ATI and Ubuntu have collaborated to develop the open source drivers.

For floppy,
try this: `udisks --mount /dev/fd0`
[Source for the command](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1772291#4)

Comment: In fact, as 16.04 user you can (and you should) install closed source drivers from AMD website. Its called "AMDGPU PRO Linux drivers" (just google it) ... its one tar.xy package which you extract and run installation script (installation proces is simple), after restart its done. Ive tested it on my RADEON RX460 and STEAM GAMES like BIOSHOCK or PLANETARY ANIHILATION works just fine with these drivers.

Answer (score 0):

ad GRAPHICS DRIVERS

In fact, as 16.04 user you can (and you should) install closed source drivers from AMD website. Its called "AMDGPU PRO Linux drivers" (just google it) ... Instalation is not that easy as clicking apply in proprietary drivers settings, but its not much more complicated.

Its one tar.xy package which you extract and run installation script, then restart. Ive tested it on UBUNTU 16.04 + RADEON RX460, and STEAM GAMES BIOSHOCK or PLANETARY ANIHILATION works just fine and fast with these drivers.